# Reverse Engineer Simple Application with IDA Pro 5

Tags: windows, assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

This application is the first application challenge on the site hackthissite.org.

The idea is to find the serial. When you enter the serial number and press ok, it pops up a message box with a password for the challenge if correct, or a message saying the serial is wrong.
To solve the challenge you are supposed to find the password which is in plaintext in the binary at 0x1670FE.

I was trying to find IDA Pro where the string you enter is compared to the serial in the binary.

I want to be able to find where it's compared, be able to change the jump to allow it to accept any wrong password, or change it so it accepts any password.

I can't seem to do this. I've found where the message box is displayed (by searching for Messagebox and adding breakpoints), where it pushes the addresses of the "Sorry" or "Correct" strings on to the stack.

I've tried adding breakpoints on the addresses of these strings and on the Serial itself, but it doesn't seem to work.
IDA doesn't seem to recognise these as strings, they don't show up in the sting window.

I've also tried to follow this function back but I reach a point where I can't seem to go back any further.

Any help, information, or tips would be greatly appreciated. I really want to know how to figure this kind of problem out.

Sorry if it is a very basic question.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you post a link to a binary which is supposedly available from a more well known source?

Comment: @paxdiablo - if I could +1 an "edit" you'd get my +1.

Comment: I'm guessing the site requires registration.

Comment: Thanjs, @Steve, I just thought there was something a little "dangerous" about an executable from someone who's learning the fine art of hacking :-)

Comment: Yes, I added the binary just to save people the trouble of having to register (I did scan it with an Antivirus first though).

Thanks for taking the time to read this anyway.

Hopefully you could give me some suggestions on how to take apart and understand this better?

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "simple" application.

Comment: It seemed simple in theory, enter some text, compare it to some other text.
After looking at it, it seems there is a little more going on.
In the end I managed to achieve what I wanted by following it through in ollydbg, maybe in this case that was just the better tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this using IDA Pro, so I gave it a go using Ollydbg.

By setting the serial to something like "TEST", after pressing Authenticate, I was able to find that string in memory or the serial itself.

By setting a breakpoint on the serial memory access, I was able to work backwards and find the comparestring function where it compared the two strings.

A little while after this, it checks if edx is greater than 2 and performs a jump. I set this to an unconditional jump and a little while after that it seems to check again if the strings are the same length, which I set to always true too.

Now the program gives the password regardless of what you enter.

Interestingly, it seems that there is 5/6 valid serials, that maybe it generates from the one in memory or gets from somewhere else. When you enter an invalid serial, it compares it to each of the serials until it finds a match and then displays the message box for success or failure.

It was a pity I couldn't find the answer to this in IDA Pro, but I think ollydbg was the better tool for the job.

If I went back in IDA and looked again, I would probably now be able to find the check.

Answer (score 1):

There is a HINT given, probably you may not have noticed. Its saying that the password is in plain-text format. 
So can you try to find more on how to know the strings inside a binary. 
Reverse Engineering doesn't always imply opening with a dis-assembler or debugger.

There are commands like strings, hexdump etc., know more on that.
 Hope it helps. :)